# how to generate a random long with 4 digits in java?

Tags: java, random

how to generate a long that is in the range of [0000,9999] (inclusive) by using the random class in java? The long has to be 4 digits.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you want to generate a number from range [0, 9999], you would use `random.nextInt(10000)`.

Adding leading zeros is just formatting:

```
String id = String.format("%04d", random.nextInt(10000));
```

Comment: It's in the previous answer, but don't forget: `Random random = new Random();`

Comment: @CodeFinity I don't see how anyone can forget to create the Random object.lol

Comment: Here what is mean by "%04", Also what can i do If I want to omit the 0

Answer (score 11):

A Java `int` will never have leading `0`(s). You'll need a `String` for that. You could use [`String.format(String, Object...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) or (`PrintStream.printf(String, Object...)`) like

```
Random rand = new Random();
System.out.printf("%04d%n", rand.nextInt(10000));
```

The format `String` `%04d` is for 0 filled 4 digits. And `Random.nextInt(int)` will be [0,10000) **or** [0,9999].